# how display multiline in tabs jquerymobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, tabs

in JqueryMobile Ui we are display tabs. In that tab have more than one word.i want to display multiline. 
How to display multi line in anchor tag using css

[Error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cojTh.png)

```css
#ui-id-1{
 border-top-left-radius: 11px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

#ui-id-2{
 font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

#ui-id-3{
 font-weight: bold;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="tabs">
     <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-tabs">
      <ul>
       <li class="ui-state-active">
        <a class="ui-btn-active" href="#one" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false" id="ui-id-1">Basic</a>
       </li>
       <li >
        <a  href="#two" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false" id="ui-id-2"> <small>BEST BUY</small><br>Premium </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#three" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false" id="ui-id-3">Premium  Plus</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div> 
  </div>
```